# app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio

ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: I am getting above error when creating app using basic Activity

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Read [mcve] and [ask]

Comment: share your gradle contents please

Answer (score 0):

welcome to codding party,

you should do this things:

> compileSdkVersion to 'android-P'
>
> Support Libraries to '28.0.0-alpha1'
>
> include api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1' in the
>   dependencies block.
>
> SDK Platform update - Android P Preview (latest)
>   targetSdkVersion 'P'

and latest job, clean sync and rebuild .